# Why am I getting 'Call to undefined method PaginatorComponent::sort()' in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I just started learning PHP,cakePHP and I am unable to sort my page.
My Controller is as follows;

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Flash', 'Paginator');
public function index() 
{
    $this->Post->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array ('limit' => 5);
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    echo $this->Paginator->sort('id');
}
```

Paginate is working fine, but for sort I get a fatal error as follows

**Call to undefined method PaginatorComponent::sort()**

could not find anything related to the error as well. It might be really basic but it will really help me to learn more, and I want to learn more! Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Update:

I added the following code in my index view,

```
<th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Id', 'id'); ?></th>
```

But now I am getting the following error
**Call to a member function sort() on null**

Comment: Have you set the `$components` for Pagination?

Comment: in my AppControler I have
public $components = array('Flash', 'Session', 'Auth', 'Paginator', 'Security');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to set pagination defaults. The proper way of doing so is defining in your controller:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'order' => array(
        'Post.id' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

or in the action:

```
$this->paginate = array (
   'limit' => 5,
   'order' => array(
        'Post.id' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

Your index action should look like this:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Post->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array (
       'limit' => 5,
       'order' => array(
           'Post.id' => 'desc'
       )
    );
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
}
```

In your view, the correct syntax for CakePHP 2.x is

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?>
```

Comment: yes , thank you... I was having trouble with the view but had figured it out after a little more re-search :)

Answer (score 0):

In my index()

```
$this->paginate = array ('limit' => 5);
```

later in my index view I used

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id','Id'); ?>
```

syntax : this->Paginator->sort('column name','label name');

Instead of normal html code. And it worked!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! The second parameter of `Paginator::sort()` is optional, and can be omitted (it defaults to an inflected form of the the key), as per [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links)..

Comment: I've edited your question to improve it's searchability.